# AWS S3 changes in a bucket / prefix using boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

What is the most efficient way (i.e. lower cost :) to check for any changes to a bucket according to a prefix?

In other words, is there a way to check if there were new/updated/deleted files in a bucket with said files stored according to a prefix?

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible solution (this feature is currently in beta it seems): Bucket Logging.

Easy to setup using the AWS Console.

Note that the delay for availability of the logs isn't too good (for some applications at least): took 1/2hour during my first test.

Some documentation available [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlogging.html).